# QR Code url encoding email address opening mail client instead of open url

Tags: email, google-visualization, qr-code, urlencode, url-encoding

In my app i am using QR code to open a web page and show a clients id and email address. The url is encoded as follows.

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200&chl=http://test.mysite.com/test.aspx?id=C112233%26un=user1%40test.com
```

but when I scan the qr code from my smartphone the link is opening the mail client and does not open the url which is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Symptom

Not all smartphone apps are created equal.  I use [Scan - QR Code and Barcode Reader](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scan-qr-code-barcode-reader/id411206394?mt=8) for iOS, and it brought that URL up in my browser window no problem.  Have you tested with more than one app? I think your app might be looking for email addresses in the QR Code data and determining the context of the data based on some conditions.

#### Solution

Try double-encoding the email address.  Google-visualization is receiving the `user1%40test.com` as `user1@test.com`.  If you send it as `user1%2540test.com`, then it will encode the URL properly, allowing your web server to receive what you intended.  One of the comments below described this as a parameter within a parameter, which is absolutely right.

Comment: You have to encode it 2 times, it's a parameter inside a parameter

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  It was marked as the right answer and I never got any feedback as to what exactly solved the problem.  I just edited the answer to make it clearer what was a symptom of the problem, and what the solution was.